# c/c++, Win API, что делает функция WideCharToMultiByte()

Tags: c, winapi, ansi, codepage

Я не совсем понимаю, что делает описанная функция.

1) Изначально я предполагал, что функция преобразует строку широких символов в строку однобайтовых символов **ANSI**. Я полагал, что в строке широких символов каждый символ занимает **16 бит**, ни больше и ни меньше.

Мне показалось все простым и логичным - функция отображает **16-ти** битные символы в **8-ми** битные, используя заданную кодовую страницу для представления.

2) Потом я узнал, что в **Windows** строки широких символов - это не строки **16-ти** битных символов, а строки юникода, в которых позиция в таблице юникода (значащий символ) может быть представлен и одним **16-ти** битным символов, и двумя.

3) А когда я стал разбираться с понятием многобайтовости, то запутался окончательно.

Названная функция выполняет преобразование **UTF-16 >> UTF-8**?

Или **UTF-16 >> ANSI(CP)**?

Или что?

Comment: Она может и в utf8 и в cp1251. Смотря что попросите. Читайте доки к функциям: [WideCharToMultiByte()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte)

Comment: Виндовая реализация `mbs* to<->from *wcs` с учётом их отношения с локалями в консоли, тип преобразования зависит от кодепейдж консоли, в общем вещь сама в себе, если по сути. Лучше смотреть [в эту](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte) сторону.